# asp.net7 docker nuget restore restoring wrong versions?

Tags: c#, docker, asp.net-core, nuget

I have an asp.net (simple) rest api app running on net7 which runs fine when when I run locally.

The rest api depends on:

- net7
- autofac
- entity framework core
- pomelo entityframeworkcore mysql
- swagger

I am developing on ubuntu, but I doubt that has much to do with this, since I am experiencing problems inside docker container which should be identical running on any OS.

When I run the app in a docker container I get an exception when I try to resolve any autofac dependencies.

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'. The system cannot find the file specified.

File name: 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext..ctor(DbContextOptions options)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext..ctor()
   at WebApplication3.Database.ProjectsDatabase..ctor()
   at lambda_method2(Closure, Object[])
   at Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.BoundConstructor.Instantiate()
```

When I log into my docker container and check which dlls are present, the dll is actually right there, but with a different version (7.0.0.0).

```
Company Name                    : Microsoft Corporation
File Description                : Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection
File Version                    : 7.0.22.51805
Internal Name                   : Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.dll
Legal Copyright                 : © Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
Original File Name              : Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.dll
Product Name                    : Microsoft® .NET
Product Version                 : 7.0.0+d099f075e45d2aa6007a22b71b45a08758559f80
Assembly Version                : 7.0.0.0
```

But the weirdest of all is, when I run the application locally:

- I don't even have the Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.dll in my bin/Debug/net7.0 folder.
- I have a **different** version of the Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.dll !

  - Running locally, I am using File Version                    : 7.0.423.11504
  - Running in docker, I am using File Version                    : 8.0.23.12803

In my csproj I am explicitly asking for `<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="[7.0.4]" />`

For reference the csproj (notice the square brackets around the version numbers, which should explicitly get that version and only that version if I am not mistaking, but the problem occurs with and without the brackets).

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
        <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
        <DockerDefaultTargetOS>Linux</DockerDefaultTargetOS>
        <RootNamespace>WebApplication3</RootNamespace>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
      <Content Include="..\.dockerignore">
        <Link>.dockerignore</Link>
      </Content>
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
      <PackageReference Include="Autofac" Version="[7.0.0]" />
      <PackageReference Include="Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection" Version="[8.0.0]" />
      <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="[7.0.4]" />
      <PackageReference Include="Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql" Version="[7.0.0]" />
      <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen" Version="[6.5.0]" />
      <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI" Version="[6.5.0]" />
    </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

For reference the docker file running the asp net rest api app

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:7.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["sb.projects.admin.app/sb.projects.admin.app.csproj", "sb.projects.admin.app/"]
RUN dotnet restore "sb.projects.admin.app/sb.projects.admin.app.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/sb.projects.admin.app"
RUN dotnet build "sb.projects.admin.app.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "sb.projects.admin.app.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "sb.projects.admin.app.dll"]
```

I have a hard time figuring out where I should be looking at to resolve this. To me it seems like nuget is resolving the wrong version.

All ideas are welcome...

Comment: Wild guess, but what if you try to add this `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions` package explicitly to your project?

Comment: @Alex tried that too, results in the same problem

Comment: @CodeCaster apologies, I tried this as some suggestion I found somewhere which results in the same problem. I'll update my question with the normal sdk from microsoft. But anyway that also doesn't work

Comment: You can try to add the following elements in your project's .csproj file:

    <PropertyGroup>
      <AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>
      <GenerateBindingRedirectsOutputType>true</GenerateBindingRedirectsOutputType>
    </PropertyGroup>